# is there any EPUB library for actionscript(adobe air)?

Tags: flash, air, epub

I want to show epub books in my mobile application that is creates with Adobe AIR.

Is there any library to solve this problem?

Comment: Most important missing information is: What **file format** are these mysterious _"epub books"_???

Comment: *An EPUB file is an archive that contains, in effect, a website. It includes HTML files, images, CSS style sheets, and other assets. It also contains metadata. EPUB 3 is the latest version. By using HTML5, publications can contain video, audio, and interactivity, just like websites in web browsers.* So, most probably, no, if there are no relevant results for **as3 epub library**, the whole task of composing a full-featured browser inside Flash app (that can also run inside web page in real browser) sounds far too complicated.

Comment: @Organis thanks for the clarification. I suspected he possibly meant PDF since some people have also called that format as e-books and e-pubs. So all he needs is the AIR stageWebView?

Comment: @VC.One Not necessarily. The "*...in effect, a website...*" does not automatically mean it is an HTML-compatible (or browser-compatible) website. Or maybe it is. In any case it requires further investigation while the absence of ready-to-use AS3 libraries tells that it may not be **that** simple after all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you might need an SDK to create your own reader, I don't think there's another way out. While there're some open-source libraries usually they lack of support and further development. So, if you're targeted to create a standalone app for iOS, Android or Xamarine you could try e. g. https://epubear.scand.com/ . It goes with a 1-year license, 1 application and they even provide cloud hosting for all the books you collect with complete DRM. And the team is easy to get in touch with. )